# Visual C++: No default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, most-vexing-parse

I've looked at a couple other questions asking this, but mine seems to be a lot simpler of a case then the ones I've been through, so I'll ask my case for this.

Learn.h:

```
#ifndef LEARN_H
#define LEARN_H

class Learn
{
public:
    Learn(int x);
    ~Learn();

private:
    const int favourite;
};

#endif
```

Learn.cpp:

```
#include "Learn.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Learn::Learn(int x=0): favourite(x)
{
    cout << "Constructor" << endl;
}

Learn::~Learn()
{
    cout << "Destructor" << endl;
}
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Learn.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "What's your favourite integer? "; 
    int x; cin >> x;
    Learn(0);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

The above code in itself does not output any error.

However, I do get a couple errors after I replace `Learn(0)` with `Learn(x)`. They are:

- Error E0291: `no default constructor exists for class Learn`
- [Error C2371](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2371?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2371)%26rd%3Dtrue): `'x' : redefinition; different basic types`
- [Error C2512](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2512?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2512)%26rd%3Dtrue): `'Learn' : no appropriate default constructor available`

Any reason for this? I really want to actually input the integer variable `x` inside it rather than the `0`. I know this is only practice and I'm new to this, but really, I'm a little confused as to why this doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You tried to specify the default value of x (in the Learn ctor) in the .cpp. You should instead define it in the header.

Comment: @ZeroUltimax is correct about the default parameter, but the real reason the compiler is complaining is that it thinks you're trying to define a function named `Learn`. You can't call a constructor quite like you're trying to. You need to use `Learn some_name(x);`.

Comment: [OT]: `Learn::Learn(int x=0)` is useless in your cpp, as the default value is only available in that cpp file. Remove it, or place it in your header.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parsing issue:

```
Learn(x);
```

is parsed as

```
Learn x;
```

You should use

```
Learn{x};
```

to build your temporary or

```
Learn some_name{x};
//or
Learn some_name(x);
```

if you want an actual object.

Comment: Maybe better give it a name: `Learn tmp{x};`

Comment: @RustyX: That is no longer a temporary, and the print of `"Destructor"` will happen after the pause. Possibly using extra scope `{Learn tmp{x};}` if you want absolutely name it.

Comment: @Jarod42 What's a temporary? Sorry, a little new to C++.
Also, bit confused as to why the change in brackets made a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the problem I was having. I didn't realize that the call is done as part of an object assignment. The notation in C++ seems to be a bit different that way.

So `Learn(x)` should be replaced with `Learn obj(x)` apparently.

This notation is a little off from other programming languages where you can usually write `className(inputs) variableName`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar code and came up with a different errors because I was compiling with Linux in a terminal. My errors were:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'myObject str' 
error: 'str' has a previous declaration as 'const string  str'
```

when I tried `myObject(str);`

Sure `Learn{x};` (and in my case `myObject{str};`) will successfully compile, but it creates a temporary object, then destroys it in the same line.

This is not what I wanted to do. So an alternative solution is to create a new object like:

`Learn var_name = new Learn(x);`

This way you can reference it for future use.